# Powershell "cmd.exe /c" with special characters

Tags: powershell

I want to to use this code:

```
cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe" /install "file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Addin.vsto"
```

and I can't get it to work no matter how I put the quotes the "(x86)" part kills it. If anyone can get this to work it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `cmd` to invoke the installer?

Here an example which uses the [Join-Path](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113347) cmdlet to combine the installer path and invokes it directly:

```
$installerPath = Join-Path $env:CommonProgramFiles 'microsoft shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe'
$parameter = @('/install', 'file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Addin.vsto')

& $installerPath @parameter
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that works but I want to use it together with psexec like this:        `psexec -u Domain\Administrator -p password -i -d \\pc-test cmd /c  "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe" /install "file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Addin.vsto"` and unfortunately psexec doesn't seem to understand the ampersand &.

Comment: and you want to call that psexec with powershell?

Comment: Yes of course, It's practically one script for a big update which needs to be done every 4 weeks or so.

Comment: you could either, try this: `psexec -u Domain\Administrator -p password -i -d \\pc-test "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe" /install "file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Addin.vsto"` or you can just save the snipet I provided as a seperate `ps1` file which you can invoke using psexec. Can't help you any further due to lack of PsExec knowledge.