# unable to silently install VSTO from powershell

Tags: powershell, vsto

Trying to install VSTO using `/silent` switch but it does not install vsto

this works

`$installerPath = Join-Path $env:CommonProgramFiles 'microsoft shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe'
$parameter = @('/install',  'file:///C:\Users\dummy.vsto')
& $installerPath @parameter`

but this does not...nothing happens (note the appending `/silent` switch)

`$installerPath = Join-Path $env:CommonProgramFiles 'microsoft shared\VSTO\10.0\VSTOInstaller.exe'
$parameter = @('/install',  'file:///C:\Users\dummy.vsto', '/silent')
& $installerPath @parameter`

I have been using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339441/powershell-cmd-exe-c-with-special-characters) as a reference

Comment: When you run the file manually, does a prompt appear or does it just start installing?

Comment: Prompt appears. Bit if a first world problem but it would be nice to not have it appear @chris

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer to why this isn't working (regardless of whether this is the right way to do it as part of an MSI install) is that the solution is not trusted. Windows must trust the certificate that was used to publish it - that certificate needs to be in the list of trusted publishers for either that machine or the user that is running this. The trust chain (the 'Certification Path' when viewing a certificate) must also be valid all the way to a root CA.

If all of this is set up right, then when you manually run the *.vsto file, the installer will automatically start installing. This is why the silent install is not working; since the solution is not trusted, it requires user input. you might find an error to this effect in the event viewer and/or the trust center log in `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Office\TCDiag`.

Further reading: [Granting Trust to Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772086.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to install a VSTO based add-in, not VSTO itself.

In that case I'd recommend creating an MSI installer for your VSTO add-in which you can run silently using command line arguments listed on the [Standard Installer Command-Line Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372024(v=vs.85).aspx) page (see `/quiet`).

The [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer) article describes all the required steps for that.

Comment: This is already Pat of an MSI install. It would be good if the MSI could install the vsto as well

Comment: Did you try to add VSTO runtime as a prerequisite?

Comment: aaahhh...no I did not...will try now

Comment: just tried..how? I am using a VS Setup project to deploy it..it is already packaged up in the File System ->Application Folder..how do I add it as a prereq?

Comment: I suppose my real question is - "How can I install a VSTO as part of an MSI install?" I think my setup.exe simply copies all the required files to the directory. I want to actually install the VSTO as well as copy all the files

Comment: Using your link I would need to use InstallShield which I am not using.

Comment: The steps are common for all kind of MSI based tools. You may consider using a Visual Studio MSI add-on or Wix.